# entity framework How to revert an already executed query if other queries fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my web application, when a user registers, I have to store his credentials in a table, his profile in another table.

```
public long CreateUser(User user) {
  using(EF db = new EF()) {
    db.AddToUsers(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return user.UserId;
  }
}

public void CreateUserAuth(UserAuth userAuth) {
  using(EF db = new EF()) {
    db.AddToUserAuths(userAuth);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

ex: When User1 registers, I save user1, city, country in Users table.
And save user1, password, CreatedOn in UserAuths table.
In this case, My code is

```
CreateUser(user);
CreateUserAuth(userAuth);  
...
```

If CreateUserAuth fails for some reason, How can I revert back the query in CreateUser?
Is there a way to achieve this without making lot of structural changes?

I created an entire website using similar functions. Now I realize that if one function fails, there is no way to revert the already executed statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: @Westie, Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can accomplish this by using transaction. This article might help you in understanding transaction
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: If I use the below code, db is destroyed and recreated, right? So can the transaction roll back the CreateUser in case of failure in CreateUserAuth?  

`using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()){    

    CreateUser(user);  

    CreateUserAuth(userAuth);  

    scope.Complete();  

}`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't let you create databases in a transaction. EF probably creates a suppressing transaction scope for the duration of the database creation.

Comment: If `scope.Complete();` is not called, then the changes are not committed.

Comment: To say DB is Destroyed and recreated in not suitable here .... Actually the purpose of transaction in database is to either executer complete code or RevertBack any changes done before submitting...after scope.Complete(); you have to set some bool indicator and submitChanges to database on the basis of that indicator.

Comment: By destroying and recreating, I mean to say that my `ef.SaveChanges` will dispose ef, right? Will the scope work in this case? Or should I change my code to use the same ef for both the CreateUser and CreateAuthUser functions? (Still in the learning mode. Please forgive my non-technical explanation)

Comment: There are a lot of places where I use such functions. Guess, I will have to make this change everywhere.   
So, in order to make the queries scope based, should I create the Ef in my controller function, pass it to the model and dispose it before returning the view?